# Scrollspy not working properly for last few elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am trying to use Scrollspy to highlight navbar elements.

HTML:

```
<body id="page-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header  ">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#benchmark">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="hover_img">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top" >Ashraf Tech<img src="img/logo.png" alt="image" height="50px" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="benchmark" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#benchmark.in">
                        <a class="active page-scroll" class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#benchmark.in">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                   <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#benchmark.in">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services" class="page-scroll" >Our Services</a>
                    </li>

                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#benchmark.in">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div>
<section id="home">
        <div class="container homecontainer">
        <div class="panel">
            <h2>
            Ashraf Technologies
            <span><p>We are here to boost your buisnees. You may be startups or an old player in industry we well enhance your image to attract more customers.</p></span>
            </h2>
            <div id="buttton"> <a href="#about"  class="btn btn-default page-scroll">Tell Me More</a></div>
        </div>
            </div><!--end of panel -->

 </section>
<section id="about">
    <div class="container about">
    <div class="panel abt">
    <h2>About us</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>
    Vision
    <p> Ashraf Tech Vision Ashraf Tech VisionAshraf Tech VisionAshraf Tech Vision Ashraf Tech Vision Ashraf Tech Vision Ashraf Tech Vision </p>
    </li>
    <li>
    Mission<p>Ashraf Tech Mission Ashraf Tech Mission Ashraf Tech Mission Ashraf Tech Mission Ashraf Tech MissionAshraf Tech MissionAshraf Tech Mission sdfsdfsdfs its end</p>
    </li>
    </ul>

    </div><!--panel end-->
    </div>
</section>

<section id="portfolio">
<div class="container">
<h2>Our Proud Customers</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/client.jpg">
                <h4> <a href="http://prajbuilders.com/">client 1</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/client.jpg">
                <h4> <a href="http://prajbuilders.com/">client 2</a> </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/client.jpg">
                <h4> <a href="http://prajbuilders.com/">client 3</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/client.jpg">
                <h4> <a href="http://prajbuilders.com/">client 4</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--end of row-->
</div>
</section>

<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
    <div id="service1">
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="panel service"><h2>Web and Mobile</h2>
            <ul>
            <li><span>Web Design and Developmemnt</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            <li><span>Android and iOS applications</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            <li><span>Website Redesign</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="service2">
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="panel service"><h2>Digital Marketing</h2>
            <ul>
            <li><span>Facebook Page and social media advertizing</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            <li><span>Web Marketing</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            <li><span>SEO</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="service3">
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="panel service"><h2>Enterprise Solutions</h2>
            <ul>
            <li><span>eCommerce Solutions</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            <li><span>.Net Development></span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            <li><span>Java Development</span></li><p><span>Lorem Ipsum sdsadf Jwer mn JHGWAMFN</span></p>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="contact">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="panel contactinfo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div class=" thumbnail  mapdisplay" id="map-canvas" style="min-height:50%; max-height:70%; min-width:50%;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 contact">
                <h2>Contact Information</h2>
                <ul>
                <li> Office contact</li><p>abc,asdasdasd asdasd 234324 </p>
                <li>contact number</li><p>21341234, 234234324 </p>
                <li>email</li><p>asdasf asfasf</p>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="panel contactus">
         <div id="formSubmitted"></div>
         <div id="formdiv">
            <h2>Have a question? Write Us </h2>
         <form  class="myform"   action="formsave.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" onSubmit="document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display = 'none';" name="form1" >


         <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2"> Name </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" required>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2"> Email Id </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please Enter Email Id" required>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="row form-group">
        <label for="Cnumber" class="col-sm-2" > Contact Number </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnumber" name="Cnumber" placeholder="Contact Number(+XX XXXXXXXXXX)" required>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="row form-group">
        <label for="msg" class="col-sm-2"> Message </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
             <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="form-control" rows="2" cols="40" placeholder="Whats Your Message" required></textarea>
            <span id="counter"></span>
        </div>
      </div>


       <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div> 
        </div>


        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
        </div>
        </div><!--End of panel -->
    </div><!--End of row -->
 </div>
</section>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(../img/background-fnl.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }

.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:15px;

    }   
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    height:100%;
}
.navbar {

    min-height: 65px;
}
.panel {
    margin:20px;
    margin-top:40px !important;
    background-color: #348AB4;
    color:#FFF;
    border-color: #FFEAFF;
    border-width:medium;
    text-align:center;
    border-image:url(../img/border-img.jpg)1 1 1 1  space repeat; 


    }
    .abt{
        background-image:url(../img/backgrnd-abt.jpg) !important;   
    }
    .panel h2 {
    text-align:center;
     font-family: "modern_no._20regular";
        }
    .panel h2 span{
        font-size: large;
        color:#FCF8A3;
        font-family:"myriadPro-Regular";}
        .logo{
            font-family: "Kaushan Script","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,cursive;
            }
.hover_img a img {
      display:none;
       }
.hover_img a:hover img {
     display:inline; 
     }
.about {
    background-image:url(../img/backgrnd-abt.jpg);
}
.about h2 {
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color:#FFF;
    margin:30px;
}
.about li {
    text-align:justify;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
    margin:30px;
    }
    .about li p {
        font-style:oblique;
        font-weight:normal;
        margin:30px;
        color:#FFC;
        }
        #services{
            overflow-y:scroll;
            }
#service1{
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service1.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:10px;
    }
    #service2{
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:10px;
    }
    #service3{
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:10px;
    }
    .service{
        background-color:transparent;
        color:#003;
        text-align:left;
        border: none;
        border-image:none;
        }
    .service h2{
        text-align:justify;}
    .service li{
        text-align:justify;
    }
    .service span{
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    .contactinfo{
        background-image:url(../img/contact-bck.jpg);
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        background-size:cover;
        color:#009;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .contact{
        float:right;
        }
    .mapdisplay{
        height:40%;
    }

    .contactus{
        background-color:#FFF;
        margin-top:25px;
        background-image:url(../img/contact.jpg);
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        background-size:cover;
        padding:10px;
    }
    .contactus h2{
        color:#003;
        text-align:center;}
    .myform{
        margin-left:15%;
        margin-right:15%;
        text-align:center;
        color:#000;
    }
@media (max-device-width:320px){
    .container {
    width: 320px !important;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.btn{
     padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  }
.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home-mob.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    #service1{
    background-image:url(../img/service1-ver.jpg);
    width: 320px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    width: 320px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service3{
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    width: 320px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    .contactus{
        color:#FFF;
        background-image:url(../img/backgrnd-abt.jpg) !important;
        }
        .contactus h2{
            color:#FFF;
            text-align:center;}
        .myform{
            margin:10px;
            text-align:center;
            color:#FFF;
            }
    }
@media (max-device-width: 450px){
    .container {
    width: 360px !important;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home-mob.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    #service1{
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service1-ver-tab.jpg);
    width: 360px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    width: 360px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service3{
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    width: 360px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    .contactus{
        color:#FFF;
        background-image:url(../img/backgrnd-abt.jpg) !important;
        }
        .contactus h2{
            color:#FFF;
            text-align:center;}
        .myform{
            margin:20px;
            text-align:center;
            color:#FFF;
            }
}
@media (max-device-width: 450px) and (orientation: landscape) {
.container {
    width: 360px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home-hor.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;}
    .btn{
         padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
        }
        #service1{
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service1.jpg);
    width: 360px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    width: 360px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }#service3{
    margin-top:25px;
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    width: 360px !important;
    background-size:contain;
    }
    .contactus{
        color:#FFF;
        background-image:url(../img/backgrnd-abt.jpg) !important;
        }
        .contactus h2{
            color:#FFF;
            text-align:center;}
        .myform{
            margin:20px;
            text-align:center;
            color:#FFF;
            }
}

    @media (max-device-width: 640px){
        .container {
    width: 560px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home-mob.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;}
    #service1{
    background-image:url(../img/service1-ver-tab.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service3{
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    .contactus{
        color:#FFF;
        background-image:url(../img/backgrnd-abt.jpg) !important;
        }
        .contactus h2{
            color:#FFF;
            text-align:center;}
        .myform{
            margin:20px;
            text-align:center;
            color:#FFF;
            }
        }
@media (max-device-width: 640px) and (min-device-width: 400px)and (orientation: landscape) {
.container {
    width: 500px;
}
.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home-hor.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    #service1{
    background-image:url(../img/service1.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    margin-top:30px;
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service3{
    margin-top:30px;
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }

}
@media (min-width: 641px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .container {
    width: 680px;
}
.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home-hor.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
.btn{
    padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 641px) {

.btn{
    padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
    }
    #service1{
    background-image:url(../img/service1-ver.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service3{
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
.btn{
    padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
    }
    #service1{
    background-image:url(../img/service1-ver-tab.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service3{
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

.btn{
    padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
    width: 1200px;
}
.homecontainer{
    background-image:url(../img/home-hor.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;}

.btn{
    padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
    }
    #service1{
    background-image:url(../img/service1.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service2{
    background-image:url(../img/service2.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
    #service3{
    background-image:url(../img/service3-fnl.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1700px) {
.container {
    width: 1770px;
}
.btn{
    padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
    }
}

.sr1 {
    background-color:#000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size:36px;
}
.sr2 {
    background-color:#00F;
    color:#FF0;
    font-size:36px;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #090d6d;
  border-color: #3a44b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #f3f5f6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #d6c0ee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #f3f5f6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #f3f5f6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #d6c0ee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #090d6d;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #f3f5f6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #d6c0ee;
  background-color: #3a44b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider {
  background-color: #3a44b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #d6c0ee;
  background-color: #3a44b2;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #d6c0ee;
  background-color: #3a44b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #d6c0ee;
  background-color: #3a44b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #3a44b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #3a44b2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #f3f5f6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #f3f5f6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #f3f5f6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #d6c0ee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #f3f5f6;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #d6c0ee;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #d6c0ee;
    background-color: #3a44b2;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(updateScrollSpy, 1000);
});
function updateScrollSpy() {
    jQuery('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = jQuery(this).scrollspy('refresh')
    });
}

$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-20
        }, 1700, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('#page-top').scrollspy({
    target: '#benchmark'
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

I have created  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhabrs36/) but its working fine there,but On my localhost only first two tabs are getting highlighted correctly. As soon as I scroll to "portfolio" it starts highlighting last element.

Can any one please help?
Thank you!!